# What does "take my word on anything" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I have stumbled upon it in this [video](https://youtu.be/kuvfYE7ZdL0). It is at 11 minutes and 22 seconds.

> I am not asking for your trust. I am not asking you to take my word on anything. In fact, I urge you *not* to **take my word on anything**.

Comment: “[Take my word](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/take-my-word-for-it)” means “believe me”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this means is that the person who is talking is giving you important facts. He is discussing something that he thinks is important. He has his own beliefs and opinions, but he does not want to just tell you to believe him based on his side of the story. That "belief" won't be rock-solid.

He is telling you that you don't have to trust what he is saying, just that you listen to what he has to say. After that, you can do your own research and see if what he told you is true. He says *"I urge you to do your own homework".*

He is urging you not to believe anything he says but to make sure that you go and do your own research to educate yourself on the issue.

According to Collins,

> If you say to someone 'take my word for it', you mean that they should believe you because you are telling the truth.

And according to Free Dictionary, to take someone's word for something or to take someone's word on something is

> to believe what someone says about something without seeking further information or proof. 
>   Example:
>
> 1. You know more about cars than I do, so if you think it needs a new gearbox, I’ll take your word for it.
> 2. Can I take your word for it that the text has all been checked?

We also say *"don't take my word for it"* when we have doubts about our opinion or beliefs.

Here is an example where two students are talking:

> I have a strong feeling that there will be very few questions in the exam from chapter 7; I am not going to study it at all. I will instead put more time studying chapter 5. But *don't take my word for it*; I don't want you to blame me just in case the professor tricks us and puts in several questions from chapter 7.

Comment: Could you tell me what "on" means in the phrase

Comment: @Dmytro - "Take my word **on**" and "take my word **for**" mean roughly the same thing. Usually, it's: _(you can) **take** my word **for** it_, or: _(you) **have** my word **on** it_, but sometimes people might mix up the wording. Check out the [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+my+word+on+it%2Ctake+my+word+for+it%2Chave+my+word+on+it%2Chave+my+word+for+it&year_start=1980&year_end=2000). Also, the way that this speaker used "anything" instead of "it" might be part of why he used "on" instead of "for". In this case, "anything" refers to "anything I say in this video."

Comment: @J.R. Thanks for the save. I really did not know how to answer that question about what "on" exactly means in that phrase.